# Need to setsockopt at the SOL_SOCKET and IPPROTO_IP levels

Tags: c++, c++11, networking, setsockopt

So basically I currently have my socket set up with

```
setsockopt(nativeSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING,
            &so_timestamping_flags, sizeof(so_timestamping_flags)
```

because I need access to the `msghdr` for timestamping reasons.  However, I also need access to the `iphdr` to pull `ttl` and a few other values from incoming datagrams.

Is it possible to `setsockopt` at more than one level per socket?

Comment: Yes. (Why not just try it and see?)

Comment: Why thank you, I incorrectly assumed it would overwrite the previous settings.

Comment: Setting an *individual* option will overwrite the existing value of only that one option.  Setting an option will not overwrite any other existing options.